# Euclidian distance between list item

Tags: python, list, dictionary, euclidean-distance

I have a list of dictionary as follows:

```
list = [{a: 3, b: 2}, {a: 7, b: 9}, {a: 9, b: 11}]
```

I want to calculate the euclidean distance between every item of the list to the every other item.

I am not able to find out how can I achieve this. Please suggest me a pythonic way to calculate it.

Answer (score 1):

select two items at a time

use itertools

```
import itertools
for pointA, pointB in itertools.combinations(list, 2):
    distance(pointA,pointB)
```

where distance is your function to get distance using points

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.combinations` to do that. Select 2 items from the list at a time.

```
from itertools import combinations
from math import sqrt
for first,second in combinations(lst,2):
    print sqrt((first['a']-second['a'])**2 + (first['b']-second['b'])**2)
```

If you want to calculate the distance considering an element with itself, use `combinations_with_replacement`.

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
for first,second in combinations_with_replacement(lst,2):
    #same_as_before
```

If you prefer all the **permutations** available rather than the **combinations**, use:

```
from itertools import permutations
for first,second in permutations(lst,2):
    #same_as_before
```

If you want to know more about **itertools**, read from 
[Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
from itertools import combinations
from math import sqrt

def get_euclidean_distance(point1, point2):
    distance = sqrt((point1['a']-point2['a'])**2 + (point1['b']-point2['b'])**2)
    return distance

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_list =[{'a':3,'b':2},{'a':7,'b':9},{'a':9,'b':11}]
    for point1, point2 in combinations(my_list,2):
            print 'Euclidean distance between', point1, 'and', point2, 'is', get_euclidean_distance(point1, point2)
```

Comment: Using `itertools.combinations` is better. But if you stick to use your solution, explicitly check so that the combinations don't repeat

Comment: @AhsanulHaque question said `every item of the list to every other item` for me it meant distance with it self as well which will be `0` all the times.

Comment: I have no objection where distance is 0. What I am telling is, if you already had `distance(a,b)`, don't calculate `distance(b,a)`, because You already have that.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque makes sense.